How to use Apache Ignite RDD with Apache Spark RDD in a web application
I created a scala web application using apache ignite and spark. The application uses ignite RDD and Spark RDD. I was only able to successfully run the application by using spark-submit. But I wonder whether there is way to run the application as a standalone web application without submitting the jar to spark and use spark and ignite contexts to connect spark master and ignite server. Can I know it is possible?

I will give you some idea about why your question is very unlikely to get a good anser. Your question is similar to questions like "Is it possible to use mysql / postgres without connecting to them ?" or "Is it possible to get my car running without installing the engine". It does not describe the objective you want to acheive. And yes, you can use a local spark context which can run inside the application. But whatever you mean by rest of it is just beyond my understanding.

Thanks @sarveshseri, I will modify the question :)
